# Fluorescent polycarbonate changing optical qualities after melting

Tags: polymers

So I'm trying to figure out how to melt fluorescent poly without it changing. What it's doing after it's melted, under UV it's fluorescing a sort of opaque white instead of it's original color. Keep in mind that normally fluorescent acrylics look almost the same under UV as they do in daylight, just a little more brilliant. However after I melt the stuff I get this opaque white crap. Could someone point me in a direction to look for answers as to what's happening, why it's happening, and how to avoid it? 
Thanks a heap[image]

About how fluorescent poly is supposed to look under UV: 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is polycarbonate? And are you clear that polycarbonate is a very different material to acrylic? Also, it might help to show a before and after for the fluorescence as that might provide some clues.

Comment: Actually I'm not positive whether it's poly or acrylic.